# Корректно ли написано предложение со словом мотивация?

Tags: управление

Интересует именно глагол, точнее два глагола, после слова мотивация.

Эти факторы положительно влияют на мотивацию работников продолжать работать.

На Грамоте сказано, что с предлогом "к" не правильно употреблять (например, на мотивацию к продолжению работы), но и по правилу ((на) мотивация(ю) чего? продолжения работы) если вставить в предложение -- звучит странно.
Если изменить на "мотивацию работников продолжать работу", то, мне кажется, уходит смысл "работать вообще", а получается продолжить конкретную работу.

Comment: Однотипные скобки внутри оборота в скобках надо исключать; для этого применяют квадратные, фигурные и угловые. Из двух дефисов тире делает Word, здесь редактор так не правит. Попробуйте alt+151. «Не правильно» в значении «ошибочно» следует писать слитно.

Comment: А если на Грамоте напишут спрыгнуть с крыши? Тут вот в чем дело, какой-то грамотей смекнул, что его скоро заменит нейросеть, и решил навернуть томик другой творческих, утонченно-субъективных норм. «Мотивация к продолжению работы» — так можно писать, не слушайте никого кроме меня.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы записала это предложение так:  ***Эти факторы положительно влияют на мотивацию работников к продолжению работы.***

Пояснение

1. Значение  слова «мотивация»  указано в словаре как "объяснение чего-либо чем-либо".

**МОТИВАЦИЯ**  ж. 1. =Мотивировка. М. чьих-л. действий, поступков. Неубедительная м.  **МОТИВИРОВКА**,  ж. 1. к Мотивировать. 2. Совокупность мотивов (1.М.), доводов для обоснования чего-л. Доказательная, неубедительная м.
Управление в русском языке. **МОТИВИРОВАТЬ** что чем. [Михаил Фёдорович] находит нужным мотивировать свой приезд какою-нибудь очевидною нелепостью (Ч.).

2. Но в настоящий момент значение этих слов **расширено**, дополнительно используются слова ***мотивация*** и ***мотивирование*** с примерно такими значениями:

«Мотивация — внутри, это невидимые «пружинки», движущие человеком. Мотивирование — снаружи, это как раз действия, которые предпринимает руководство, дабы направить энергию человека в нужное русло». https://www.top-personal.ru/issue.html?1728

Итак, *мотивация* – это **внутреннее состояние** человека, а *мотивировать* – это  формировать **такое состояние**.  Но тогда получается следующий вариант: *мотивировать* и *мотивация* (кого? к чему?). Такое значение вполне понятно современным пользователям.

3. На Грамоте.ру  много вопросов на эту тему [http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=мотивация](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Но эти ответы верны только для значения мотивации **как "объяснение",** что соответствует словарям. Новая языковая ситуация не учитывается, вот в чем противоречие.